# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I upgraded my app to cordova 8.1.2 and set target sdk version to 8.0.0, my app is working just fine on kitkat and above but below kitkat it is crashing due to some webview methods. Here is the exception I am getting and I am unable to find a solution yet:

> 09-12 15:40:00.634 1732-1732/com.tracer.joblogic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled
>           at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.enableRemoteDebugging(SystemWebViewEngine.java:226)
>           at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.initWebViewSettings(SystemWebViewEngine.java:177)
>           at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.init(SystemWebViewEngine.java:108)
>           at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:112)
>           at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:149)
>           at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:224)
>           at com.tracer.joblogic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I have set min sdk version to 15 and also I tried with 16 and 19 as well but on 19 it is giving exception for

> evaluateJavascript